# JPA counterpart to Hibernate IdTransferringMergeEventListener

Tags: hibernate, jpa, merge

I want to switch my application from pure Hibernate to JPA 2.0. The application uses the IdTransferringMergeEventListener implemented by Spring to put back a newly generated database ID to the entity-reference if a new entity gets persisted. Therefore the hibernate "merge" event is listened to.

My question:

Is there a way to do this when using a JPA 2.0 EntityManager (we're using the Hibernate implementation of JPA)?

A testcase like this should work when using JPA:

```
    Entity myNewEntity = new Entity();
    entityManager.merge(myNewEntity);
    assertNotNull(myNewEntity.getId());
```

There is loads of already existing code so it is not an option to change code to this (which would work):

```
    Entity myNewEntity = new Entity();
    myNewEntity = entityManager.merge(myNewEntity);
    assertNotNull(myNewEntity.getId());
```

Is there anyone who can provide some tipps or hints? Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks, chris